# TypeError in pySpark UDF functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I've got this function:

```
def ead(lista):
    ind_mmff, isdebala, isfubala, k1, k2, ead = lista
    try:
        isdebala = float(isdebala)
        isfubala = float(isfubala)
        k1 = float(k1)
        k2 = float(k2)
        ead = float(ead)
    except ValueError:
        return 'Error: invalid input'        
    min_deb = min(0, isdebala)
    min_fub = min(0, isfubala)
    
    if ind_mmff == '0':
        ead_dai = abs(min_deb * k1 / 100 + min_fub * k2 / 100)
    else:
        ead_dai = ead
    return ead_dai
```

Afterwards, I define a UDF such as:

```
ead_udf = udf(lambda z: ead(z), FloatType())
```

The aim is to create a `ead_calc` column in my df dataframe such as:

```
df = df.withColumn('ead_calc', ead_udf (array(df.ind_mmff, df.isdebala, df.isfubala, df.k1, df.k2, df.ead_final_motor)))
```

After executing `df.select('ead_calc').show()` the following error raises:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3026.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 813.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 813.0 (TID 12054, csslncclowp0006.unix.aacc.corp, executor 2): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 345, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 141, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 334, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-93-25e605cffdae>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<ipython-input-92-a1937fe32209>", line 12, in ead
TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The error is located at `min_deb = min(0, isdebala)`. Don't know how to solve this issue since min function  obviously requires 2 arguments.

The aim is to create a ead_calc column in my df dataframe such as:

```
df = df.withColumn('ead_calc', ead_udf (array(df.ind_mmff, df.isdebala, df.isfubala, df.k1, df.k2, df.ead_final_motor)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have imported the wrong `min` function, I guess you have imported the one from pyspark by using `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`, the pyspark [min](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.min.html) function takes only one argument (column) but the python one takes two arguments

Trying to import only the needed functions and it seems working (Just added some random input)

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array

from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, FloatType

def ead(lista):
    ind_mmff, isdebala, isfubala, k1, k2, ead = lista
    try:
        isdebala = float(isdebala)
        isfubala = float(isfubala)
        k1 = float(k1)
        k2 = float(k2)
        ead = float(ead)
    except ValueError:
        return 'Error: invalid input'        
    min_deb = min(0, isdebala)
    min_fub = min(0, isfubala)
    
    if ind_mmff == '0':
        ead_dai = abs(min_deb * k1 / 100 + min_fub * k2 / 100)
    else:
        ead_dai = ead
    return ead_dai


ead_udf = udf(lambda z: ead(z), FloatType())


schema = StructType([
  StructField('ind_mmff', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('isdebala', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('isfubala', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('k1', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('k2', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('ead_final_motor', FloatType(), True)
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0)],schema=schema)

df = df.withColumn('ead_calc', ead_udf (array(df.ind_mmff, df.isdebala, df.isfubala, df.k1, df.k2, df.ead_final_motor)))

df.show()
```

```
+--------+--------+--------+---+---+---------------+--------+                   
|ind_mmff|isdebala|isfubala| k1| k2|ead_final_motor|ead_calc|
+--------+--------+--------+---+---+---------------+--------+
|     1.0|     2.0|     3.0|4.0|5.0|            6.0|     6.0|
+--------+--------+--------+---+---+---------------+--------+
```